# Can I define a complex type with another complex type in XSD without directly copying and pasting

Tags: xml, xsd

for example

```
<xs:complexType name="AddDogRequest">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="breed" type="xs:string/>
    <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string/>
    <xs:element name="age"   type="xs:string/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Dog">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="breed" type="xs:string/>
    <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string/>
    <xs:element name="age"   type="xs:string/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

What I **do not** want to do:

```
<xs:complexType name="AddDogRequest">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="dog" type="Dog"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Dog">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="breed" type="xs:string/>
    <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string/>
    <xs:element name="age"   type="xs:string/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Is there a way to define AddDogRequest in terms of Dog without adding an element to AddDogRequest. In oder words is there a way to have contents of Dog under AddDogRequest such that it is equivalent to copying and pasting Dog's content directly:

```
<xs:complexType name="AddDogRequest">
  <xs:sequence>
    !!put contents of Dog here directly??? without copy and paste
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Dog">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="breed" type="xs:string/>
    <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string/>
    <xs:element name="age"   type="xs:string/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: `<xs:element name="dog" type="xs:Dog"/>` is nonsense anyway, any type you define will normally not be in the `xs` schema namespace.

Comment: You haven't explained why you need this or what you want to achieve, one reason could be you want a common supertype, in XSD 1 substitution groups https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#SubsGroups would be the closest thing.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes thats true.......but this is just detail i will be using a defined target namespace instead of xs:Dog...

Comment: @MartinHonnen also I want to have AddDogRequest be another name for Dog..ie maybe an alias..